# how do i refresh the answer in a popup

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am just trying to make an dice roller with gui. I created a popup window which displays a random number from 1 to 6 `random.randint(1,6)`. I asigned it to a variable called number `number = random.randint(1,6)` but it always gives the same number.  I just need it to not spit out always the same number when i click on the button

```
def popup_showinfo(): 
      showinfo("You rolled", number)
number = random.randint(1,6) 
class Application(ttk.Frame):`

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        self.button_showinfo = ttk.Button(self, text="Roll", command=popup_showinfo)
        self.button_showinfo.pack()

    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: create minimal example which output the same error and post it.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is not enough code here to test.

Comment: I think you actually managed to detract from your question with your last edit. Please provide enough code for us to copy paste and see the error when we run the code. You just don't have enough here do anything with.

Comment: is it helpful if i put the whole code? im new to this

Comment: That is why I linked to the page that describes what a MCVE is. We do not need all your code. Just enough to reproduce the problem. This normally consist of your imports the main tkinter application code like `root = Tk()` and `root.mainloop()` with just enough code inside to work. Like a single button and the function you are having problems with.

Comment: okay its not long, thats basically it...all i have

Comment: plus the import stuff

Comment: That's a little better. What is the `ShowInfo()` function meant to do? You reference it in the popup function but dont have it in your example. Is show info updating a label or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so your question is not quite complete but I think I get the point of what you need.

My below answer will server 2 purposes here. One is to show you was a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code looks like. The 2nd is to produce the affect you are looking for.

Instead of having a function outside of your class you can better manage things with a method(class function) inside of your class. So lets move that popup function into the class. Next we can update a label with your random int. Keep in mind the way you code is set up now the random number will only be produced once on program start up. Instead you want to have the random int code inside the method so a new number is created each time you run the method.

With adding a label directly to the class and calling an update to the label from the new method we can roll a number between 1 and 6.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import random


class Application(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.showinfo_label = ttk.Label(self)
        self.showinfo_label.pack()

        self.button_showinfo = ttk.Button(self, text="Roll", command=self.showinfo).pack()

    def showinfo(self): 
        number = random.randint(1,6)
        self.showinfo_label.config(text="You rolled {}".format(number))


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Keep in mind when we talk about a the MCVE my code above is what we are looking for. The very minimum needed to produce an affect or at least reproduce an error.

This includes all required imports, the root and mainloop() code and the little bit of code needed to do a specific thing.

Update:

It did appear you were trying to use the `showinfo` method from Tkinter's messagebox methods so here is an example using that as well.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo


class Application(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.button_showinfo = ttk.Button(self, text="Roll", command=self.showinfo).pack()

    def showinfo(self): 
        number = random.randint(1,6)
        showinfo("You rolled ", "{}".format(number))


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try to improve my MCVE method of typing

Comment: @dan0 I added a 2nd example using tkinters `showinfo()` method as well though its probably not the best option here. You may be better off making your own pop up with `toplevel()` or using another messagebox window.

Comment: Okay i have a second question, how can i change the looks of the popup window? Like make it fit the text or other cosmetics

Comment: Well there are many different popup windows with different looks for different needs but to have a truly customer window to fit your exact needs you will need to look into the `TopLevel()` method and design your own popup.

Comment: If my answer has solved your problem in your question please select the check mark next to my answer.